# Generic extension method for generic list's

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods, automapper

These are my domain and view classes:

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class City:Entity
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class BaseViewModel:IBaseViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class CityModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

This is my mapping extension:

```
public static TModel ToModel<TModel>(this IEntity entity) 
    where TModel : IBaseViewModel
{
    return (TModel)Mapper.Map(entity, entity.GetType(), typeof(TModel));
}
```

This is how it's used:

```
City city = GetCity();
CityModel model = city.ToModel<CityModel>();
```

but for generic lists it doesn't work:

```
List<City> cities = GetCities();
List<CityModel> model =cities.ToModel<CityModel>() // doesn't work
```

Is it possible to write an extension method for a generic list?

Comment: that extension method for generic list,i got converting error

Comment: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<City>' to 'IEntity'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need something like this

```
public static List<TModel> ToModel<TModel>(this IEnumerable<IEntity> entity) 
    where TModel : IBaseViewModel
{
    // magic
}
```

Comment: `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Its a more linq way.

Answer (score 1):

Your extension method accepts a single entity and returns a single model. You'll need to add an overload for Lists. Something like this:

```
public static List<TModel> ToModel<TModel>(this List<IEntity> entityList)
    where TModel : IBaseViewModel
{
    return (List<TModel>)Mapper.Map(entityList, entityList.GetType(), typeof(List<TModel>));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the other answers, you should look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for mapping to and from Entites